# SQL - How to alter collation on an existing view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing view.
I need to change the collation on one of the columns in the view.
How can I achieve this using T-SQL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2, col3 COLLATE The_Name_Of_The_Collation_You_Want as col3, col4....`

Comment: Do you mean something like this:

Comment: ALTER VIEW [dbo].[PS_CP_TRACKUSER_VW]
AS
SELECT NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN as NAME

Comment: This was an easy Google search...

Comment: @Coloplast yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Do you mind sharing your findings?

Comment: It's coming up with "Invalid column NAME'

Comment: @Coloplast well, I don't actually know the column names of your table, I'm assuming it was modifying your actual code

Comment: Do I need all the columns in the code?
The code I posted contains the view name and the name of the column I need to change collation on.
It would be great if you could present a final script.

Comment: I can't present a final script because I don't have the code for your view. I don't get it, your current code should be something like `ALTER VIEW blablabla SELECT something`, and you need to change the `SELECT something` to modify the collation of the column you want

Comment: @Coloplast can you edit your question and include the `select` statement you are using? Also include which column's collation you want to change and which collation would you like to apply to that column. Based on Lamak's comment, you should be able to create the script yourself. It'd be a great learning exercise for you creating script yourself rather than someone creating it for you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
Alter View YourViewName
AS
Select Yourcolumn Whatever_collation_you_need
from YourTable
```

Also, if you need to link your view with another table or view, you could just specify the collation like this, with no need to alter your view:

```
select
*
from v_Filiales f --> this is a view
inner join t_Persona p --> this is a table
on p.cPerCodigo = f.cPerJuridica COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Should add `as [columnName]` as comment above. `select [Code] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` **_AS [Code]_** `from table`.